# CodeIgniter 3: Insert/delete html table row on button click with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm new in CodeIgniter. and I'm having some trouble inserting/deleting a new empty row on my table.

**Button**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="add_item"  onClick="addMoreSib();" style="display:none" id="addSibling"><li class="fa fa-plus"></li></button> 

<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="del_item" onClick="deleteRow();" style="display:none" id="deleteSibling"><li class="fa fa-minus"></li></button>
```

**Here's the jquery**

```
function addMoreSib() {
                $("<td>").load("sib_input.php", function() {
                        $("#sibTable").append($(this).html());
                }); 
            }
function deleteRow() {
                    $('TR.product-item').each(function(index, item){
                        jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
                            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                $(item).remove();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
```

**sib_input.php**

```
<tr class="product-item">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-input" value="+63-0000000000" placeholder="+63-00000000" disabled id="guardiancontact"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" name="sib_age[]" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"></td>
<td><input class="form-control"name="sib_occupation[]"></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="sib_educ_attain[]" >
        <option value="" selected>-Please select-</option>
        <option value="less than high school">less than high school</option>
        <option value="Some college but no degree">Some college but no degree</option>
        <option value="Associates Degree">Associates Degree</option>
        <option value="Elementary Graduate">Elementary Graduate</option>
        <option value="Secondary Graduate">Secondary Graduate</option>
        <option value="College Graduate">College Graduate</option>
        <option value="Master's Degree">Master's Degree</option>
        <option value="Professional Degree">Professional Degree</option>
        <option value="Doctorate Degree">Doctorate Degree</option>
        </select></td>  
</tr>

<script>
            function isNumberKey(evt)
            {
                var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
                if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                        return false;
                    return true;
            }

</script>
```

[Here is the image of how I wanted it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1ueG.png)

The problem is that, everytime I click the "+" button the form submits and refreshes with codeigniter, I have tried this without CodeIgniter and It works fine.

How can I make this work without making the page refresh?

Comment: There seems many problems, 1) Where is `#sibTable` in HTML ? 2) Your `deleteRow` function is only removing rows from front, its not removing it from DB, if it was saved before in DB.

Comment: Try changing type="submit" to type="button"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change button type from 'submit' to 'button'**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="add_item"  onClick="addMoreSib();" style="display:none" id="addSibling"><li class="fa fa-plus"></li></button> 

<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="del_item" onClick="deleteRow();" style="display:none" id="deleteSibling"><li class="fa fa-minus"></li></button>
```

Comment: Thanks , however my sib_input.php file can't be found. where am I suppose to place it? Am I suppose to load it in the controller?

Comment: You have to give relative path. You can accept my answer if it's working.